# Networking optimization for UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

i'm writing a super simple photo sharing app for practice using parse.com as my server.

i have a tableview that just shows photos a user has uploaded to the server. if nothing is persisted and this guy has a million photos uploaded to the server, what would be the best way to fetch the photos?

I know that the simple way is to make one request on viewdidload and store everything in memory before persisting it. but is there a better way? ideally i could pull photos in batches, and as the user scrolled, it would pull new photos. perhaps there is a library you know of that helps with this?

Comment: I recently answered a similar question about a collection view here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31818527/294949.  Same ideas apply, just replace collection view methods with their table view counterparts.

Comment: Have you looked at the LazyTableImages sample code from apple? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do the entire thing yourself, you should use [`SDWebImage`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

A typical code example looks like

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/olivier.poitrey/picture"]
                 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar-placeholder.png"]
                          options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

Comment: Does this work in a table view that's scrolling?  A solution like this might look strange if the request completes and the cell containing the image view corresponds to a new index path (reused while scrolling).  User can see a flash of the wrong image before the next request (at the new index path) completes.

Comment: @danh Well, the scrolling in tableview is handles much more elegantly than that. A `UITableViewCell` is not shown on the screen immediately. It's created while it's still a little bit out of the screen. The user won't see the flash of the old image at all, if one is loading the imageURLs correctly for indexPath.

Comment: I think you're mistaken about there being a delay.  The dequeued cell is passed to the datasource to configure and then shown.  A delay wouldn't make sense, it would make scrolling always stutter.  Moreover, an image loads in an arbitrary amount of time, how would the table know how long to delay before the cell was ready?  Though, I think I'm mistaken, too.  The reason the this idea probably won't manifest the problem I raised is that the placeholder image (hopefully including nil) is set in the image view asynchronously, replacing the previous "wrong" image while the right one loads.

Comment: @danh First a cell is dequeued and setup with `SDWebImage`. It would take sometime to get its image from network, so during that time, either it will show the placeholder or nothing. If the image is fetched while the cell is still showing, the image is shown. If this cell is dequeued while the image was still not fetched from network, the whole thing starts over. So for sometime, no image or placeholder is shown. But it would never show incorrect image.